# Cannot Update Data When Using Confirm Password (compare rule) in YII model

Tags: yii

In the registration form, used password field and confirm password field. After using this data cannot be updated. 
Model

```
public function rules()
    {
            // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
            return array(
                    array('name, password', 'required'),
                    array('password', 'compare', 'compareAttribute'=>'confirm_password'), 
                    array('name', 'length', 'max'=>55),
                    // The following rule is used by search().
                    // Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
                    array('id, name', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
            );
    }
```

Trying to update user model from index.php

```
`$post= User::model()->findByPk(1); $post->name='Abcdef'; $post->password='newpassword'; $post->save();`
```

The new data not updated? when it solve?

Answer (score 1):

The update won't work because the `confirmpassword` has not been set. If the password is not required on update include a [scenario](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CModel#scenario-detail) for the password else it will always be checked.

```
     public function rules()
     {
        // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
        return array(
                array('name', 'required'),
                array('password', 'required','on'=>'create'),
                array('password', 'compare', 'compareAttribute'=>'confirmpassword','on'=>'create'),
                array('name', 'length', 'max'=>55),
                // The following rule is used by search().
                // Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
                array('id, name', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
        );
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    public $confirmpassword;

    public function rules()
    {
            // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
            return array(
                    array('name, password, confirmpassword', 'required'),
                    array('password', 'compare', 'compareAttribute'=>'confirmpassword'), 
                    array('name', 'length', 'max'=>55),
                    // The following rule is used by search().
                    // Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
                    array('id, name', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
            );
    }
```